# C++ Collection of different types of static elements

Tags: c++, static, allocation

C++ Collection of different types of static elements

Greetings! Unfortunately my C++ is not very good. For an embedded system, I need to implement the task using ONLY STATIC memory allocation.

There are several groups of registers that have a virtual address. I made a primitive description of the register group like this:

```
using RegisterType = uint32_t;


template <uint8_t cnt, uint16_t addr>
class Registers
{
public:
     uint16_t count {cnt}; //Must be declared before data
     uint16_t startAddr {addr}; //Must be declared before data
     RegisterType data[cnt];
};
```

Next, I need a collection of these groups. I made a primitive description of the collection like this:

```
template <uint8_t cnt>
class RegistersGroup
{
   public:
     Registers<0, 0>* group[cnt];// I really don’t like this type cast
};
```

This code works:

```
int main()
{
     Registers<5, 0x0000> r1;
     Registers<2, 0x00FF> r2;
     RegistersGroup<2> g;
    
     r1.data[0] = 11;
     r1.data[1] = 12;
     r1.data[2] = 13;
     r1.data[3] = 14;
     r1.data[4] = 15;
    
     r2.data[0] = 11;
     r2.data[1] = 22;
    
     g.group[0] = (Registers<0, 0>*)&r1;
     g.group[1] = (Registers<0, 0>*)&r2;
    
     std::cout<<r1.count<<std::endl;
     std::cout<<r2.count<<std::endl;
    
     std::cout<<g.group[0]->startAddr<<std::endl;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < g.group[0]->count; ++i)
         std::cout<<g.group[0]->data[i]<<std::endl;
        
     std::cout<<g.group[1]->startAddr<<std::endl;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < g.group[1]->count; ++i)
         std::cout<<g.group[1]->data[i]<<std::endl;
    
     return 0;
}
```

But it only works when declaring the fields "count", "startAddr" before the field "data", since in the class "RegistersGroup" the type is reduced to "Registers<0, 0>". I'm not sure if this code will work on other compiler versions and platforms. Is it possible to make the solution more beautiful?

Comment: *" Is it possible to make the solution more beautiful?..."*  Completely subjective and opinion based.

Comment: *"I really don’t like this type cast..."* I don't think that is a type cast.

Comment: You can use tuple as a heterogeneous collection. `auto groups{::std::make_tuple(Registers<5, 0x0000>{...},  Registers<2, 0x00FF>{....})};` Note that `g.group[0]->` dereference in your code leads to Undefined Behavior since type of the object pointer actually points to does not match `Registers<0, 0>`.

Comment: Should getting a register from the group work in runtime, or is it fine do it compile-time only, e.g. `g.get<0>()`?

Comment: 1) As user12002570 stated, this question asks for opinions, which is expressly forbidden on stackoverflow.
2) Static memory allocation is a C concept, "Static" has 3 primary uses in C++, memory allocation is not one of them.
3) What you are doing in your main is allocating memory on the stack, but your question indicates you want to use pre-allocated memory.
4) In general, but particularly in embedded systems, pre-allocated memory is provided by a linker script, suffix .ld. The labels you specify within allow you to reference addresses in a more human readable way.